# Custom Button in a ClientRowTemplate on the Telerik MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

Sorry if this is a repeat.  I did a search and didn't find anything that exactly matched my situation.

I have a grid that requires a ClientRowTemplate.  I have the template working very well.

I need a button in that RowTemplate that calls back to a controller method through ajax.  The controller method needs to perform some complex logic and then return a new set of data to the grid which the grid will then need to bind to.  I thought this should work in the same fashion as an ajax binding.  For instance, when you do a save or delete (using the built in buttons) an ajax method that is attributed with [GridAction] is called and then has an IQueryable returned.  The grid automatically binds to this IQueryable.

How do I do the same thing with a custom button?  Is it even possible to add a custom button when using a ClientRowTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a link in the clienttemplate of your grid row

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<myModel>()
.Name("myGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
        @* You can put a link in your client template to trigger a refresh function *@
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:refreshGrid(<#= Id #>);'>Refresh</a>");
        columns.Bound(e => e.col1);
        columns.Bound(e => e.col2);
        columns.Bound(e => e.col3);
})
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("myGrid_onRowDataBinding"))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Action", "Controller", new { param1 = ..., param2 = ... } )))
```

Write your code to refresh grid

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //parameters needed for grid
    var x = ...;
    var y = ...;

    //grid refresh function
    function refreshGrid(id) {
        //make a call to server
        $.post("/controller/action/" + id, function() {

            //after making a successfull call to server
            //you may update parameters 
            x = ...;
            y = ...;

            //and rebind your grid
            $('#myGrid').data('tGrid').rebind();
        })        
    }

    //grid on row data binding event
    function myGrid_onRowDataBinding(e) {
        e.data = $.extend(e.data, { param1: x, param2: y });
    }
</script>
```

That's it

**EDIT:**

**ClientRowTemplate example**

You need to change only the grid code. The rest is same.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<myModel>()
.Name("myGrid")   
.ClientRowTemplate(grid => "<div class='firstcolumn'><a href='javascript:refreshGrid(<#= Id #>);'>Refresh</a></div><div class='secondcolumn'>Content....</div>")
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnDataBinding("myGrid_onRowDataBinding"))
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("Action", "Controller", new { param1 = ..., param2 = ... } )))
```

Comment: I am not using a ClientTemplate but rather a ClientRowTemplate.  The answer may be the same but I wanted to clarify.

Comment: They both are almost the same thing. ClientTemplate is used for cells, ClientRowTemplate is used for whole row. But the usage is same. I am going to edit my answer for ClientRowTemplate version.